# How can I change repository mirror from commandline?

Tags: apt, mirrors

On the desktops, the package managers have convenient ways to change the sources.list for apt-get between different mirrors.

Is there a similar menu-kind of way of doing this from the command line (i.e. on a server)?

(I am not looking for answer like using sed or manually editing the sources.list file, I know how to do that. I am looking for some application that knows the addresses of the mirrors similar to the package manager GUIs).

Comment: There are answers here https://askubuntu.com/a/1093473/897087 now

Answer (score 2):

For Debian there is [apt-spy](http://packages.debian.org/stable/apt-spy), maybe it's possible to adapt it to Ubuntu (it would need to use a different mirror list of course).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard about anything like that and most likely it doesn't exist.

I'd try contributing to the community by creating such a program (should not be a difficult task).