# How to switch APT mirror from the commandline?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Let's assume that we are using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

I know GUI ways to switch currently used APT mirror.

User should open *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk` or `software-properties-kde`) and navigate to *Ubuntu Software* (*Kubuntu Software*) tab and then select mirror in *Download from* list:

[image: picking mirror]

But how to switch APT mirror from the commandline?

**Notes/updates:**

1. I need a solution without direct editing of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to prevent typos and automate correct mirror selection.
2. I need to switch mirror with one simple command as equivalent of picking one from *Download from* list in `software-properties-gtk` (also it is interesting where mirror addresses are saved in the system).
   3. I created [discussion and poll named "Does Ubuntu need console alternative for software-properties-gtk / software-properties-kde?" on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/does-ubuntu-need-console-alternative-for-software-properties-gtk-software-properties-kde/8763?u=norbert).

Comment: Why don't you want to edit `sources.list`? That's kind of the way to do it from the command line. All the GUI tools do is manipulate that file anyway.

Comment: So you're OK if the solution does edit the file just as long as the solution isn't "go edit the file yourself"? SO, for instance, a sed command would work for you? If so, please show us an example of the alternate mirror's URL.

Comment: My main idea is the following. I need to switch mirror with one simple command as equivalent of picking one from *Download from* list in `software-properties-gtk` (also it is interesting where mirror addresses are saved in the system).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

List of mirror servers are retrieved by Python library (the `get_server_list` procedure is defined in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py` and called from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py`).

The solution is to use tool named [`apt-mirror-updater`](https://apt-mirror-updater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html). It is installable from `pip`/`pip3`:

```
sudo pip3 install apt-mirror-updater
```

Functionality:

> Usage: apt-mirror-updater [OPTIONS]
>
> The apt-mirror-updater program automates robust apt-get mirror
>   selection for Debian and Ubuntu by enabling discovery of available
>   mirrors, ranking of available mirrors, automatic switching between
>   mirrors and robust package list updating.
>
> Supported options:
>
> -r, --remote-host=SSH_ALIAS
>
> ```
> Operate on a remote system instead of the local system. The SSH_ALIAS
> argument gives the SSH alias of the remote host. It is assumed that the
> remote account has root privileges or password-less sudo access.
> ```
>
> -f, --find-current-mirror
>
> ```
> Determine the main mirror that is currently configured in
> /etc/apt/sources.list and report its URL on standard output.
> ```
>
> -b, --find-best-mirror
>
> ```
> Discover available mirrors, rank them, select the best one and report its
> URL on standard output.
> ```
>
> -l, --list-mirrors
>
> ```
> List available (ranked) mirrors on the terminal in a human readable format.
> ```
>
> -c, --change-mirror=MIRROR_URL
>
> ```
> Update /etc/apt/sources.list to use the given MIRROR_URL.
> ```
>
> -a, --auto-change-mirror
>
> ```
> Discover available mirrors, rank the mirrors by connection speed and update
> status and update /etc/apt/sources.list to use the best available mirror.
> ```
>
> -u, --update, --update-package-lists
>
> ```
> Update the package lists using `apt-get update', retrying on failure and
> automatically switch to a different mirror when it looks like the current
> mirror is being updated.
> ```
>
> -x, --exclude=PATTERN
>
> ```
> Add a pattern to the mirror selection blacklist. PATTERN is expected to be
> a shell pattern (containing wild cards like `?' and `*') that is matched
> against the full URL of each mirror.
> ```
>
> -m, --max=COUNT
>
> ```
> Don't query more than COUNT mirrors for their connection status
> (defaults to 50). If you give the number 0 no limit will be applied.
>
> Because Ubuntu mirror discovery can report more than 300 mirrors it's
> useful to limit the number of mirrors that are queried, otherwise the
> ranking of mirrors will take a long time (because over 300 connections
> need to be established).
> ```
>
> -v, --verbose
>
> ```
> Increase logging verbosity (can be repeated).
> ```
>
> -q, --quiet
>
> ```
> Decrease logging verbosity (can be repeated).
> ```
>
> -h, --help
>
> ```
> Show this message and exit.
> ```

So it allows to find best mirror and apply it to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo apt-mirror-updater --auto-change-mirror
```

Also it allows to select mirror by URL and apply it to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
$ apt-mirror-updater --list-mirrors
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rank | Mirror URL                                        | Available? | Updating? | Last updated   | Bandwidth      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1 | http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu                   | Yes        | No        | Up to date     | 6.49 KB/s      |
|    2 | http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu               | Yes        | No        | Up to date     | 6.38 KB/s      |
|    3 | http://ftp.aso.ee/ubuntu                          | Yes        | No        | Up to date     | 5.62 KB/s      |
|    4 | http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu        | Yes        | No        | Up to date     | 4.77 KB/s      |
|    5 | http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu               | Yes        | No        | Up to date     | 4.68 KB/s      |
...
```

and then select mirror by hand:

```
sudo apt-mirror-updater -c "http://mirror.timeweb.ru/ubuntu"
```

Answer (score 9):

Some solution (tested on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS): https://github.com/jblakeman/apt-select.git

### Install:

```
pip install apt-select
```

or:

```
pip3 install apt-select
```

Adding script to PATH to run it from everywhere ([make it permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)):

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/apt-select
```

### Examples usage:

Get the top mirror from the United States to generate a new sources.list::

```
apt-select --country US
```

Choose from the top 3 mirrors, including those last updated a week ago::

```
apt-select -c -t 3 -m one-week-behind
```

Select from 5 US mirrors with the lowest latency to your machine:

```
$ apt-select --country US -t 5 --choose
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner that doesn't require installing any additional tools...

```sh
APT_MIRROR=au
sed --in-place --regexp-extended "s/(\/\/)(archive\.ubuntu)/\1${APT_MIRROR}.\2/" /etc/apt/sources.list
```