# Ubuntu server 16.04 unable upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, server, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

This is my server:

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-142-generic **x86_64**)

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I want to upgrade it at ubuntu server 18.04

`more /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
Prompt=lts
```

`$ sudo do-release-upgrade`
or
`$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

> Descargando Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   bionic-updates/main i386 unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386
>   unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Obtenidos 0 B en 0s (0 B/s)
>   Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386
>   unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386
>   unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Obtenidos 0 B en 0s (0 B/s)
>   Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386
>   unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Error http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386
>   unattended-upgrades all 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8
>
> 404  Not Found
>   Obtenidos 0 B en 0s (0 B/s)
>        **Failed to fetch  http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8_all.deb**
>
> 404 Not Found

I had verified file dosn't exists however the file
http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.**18.04.9**_all.deb exists

`sudo do-release-upgrade -c`

```
[sudo] password for xxxxxx: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

I get the same result when applying the list of mirrors obtained with `apt-select --country ES` (example: mirror.tedra.es)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch APT mirror from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093451/how-to-switch-apt-mirror-from-the-commandline)

Comment: I get the same result when applying the list of mirrors obtained with apt-select --country ES (example: http://mirror.tedra.es)

Comment: Then simply switch to main server (`archive.ubuntu.com`).

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.8_all.deb was not found on this server but http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_1.1ubuntu1.18.04.9_all.deb exists

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt update`?