# Slow apt-get update on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and running `apt-get update` takes too much time (more than 30 minutes). Installing packages afterwards is very fast. I have decent Internet connection (~100 MB/s download speed), SSD as data storage.

I tried removing all but one repository from `sources.list` and `sources.list.d`. However, the result did not change much, every single package list is still taking a lot of time.

Most of the time running `sudo apt-get update` hangs on the following line:

```
my@laptop:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
0% [1 InRelease 247 kB/247 kB 100%]
```

And stays there for quite a while.

I can re-run `sudo apt-get update` few times, and then some package lists will get through, but ultimately `apt` will hang again on another list like the above one.

UPDATE: some people suggested changing package lists to `http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/` or just `http://archive.ubuntu.com/`. I tried that, the result is still the same - `sudo apt-get update` takes a lot of time.

I checked my network, all websites load fast, Slack and Pidgin apps work well, so I am not sure it is network issue.

Comment: This is a matter of the network connaection at your side and the `nl` mirror.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch APT mirror from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093451/how-to-switch-apt-mirror-from-the-commandline)

Comment: @user535733 Just tried this, does not seem to help

Comment: Then it's time to do your basic network troubleshooting: Power cycle your router. Check your cables. Run a speedtest.

Comment: @user535733 My network seems to be doing well, websites load fast, apps like Slack and Pidgin work well, ssh works well. Only `apt` seems to be very slow, I changed package lists to point to different endpoints - did not help.

Comment: Then try different mirrors until you find a fast one.